# How to read some number and then use it in calculations

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have one question, can I make something, that would read any noumber and than use that number in calculations?

```
String s1 = editText.getText().toString();
if (s1.contains("H--some number--")) {
d += (H * --some number--);
}
```

When user types H2, i want to read that 2 and than use is in calculations, but user can also type other numbers. For example H5 and than i need H * 5. Do i need to write every possible input?

```
 s1.contains(H2) ; s1.contains(H5)
```

Thanks for answer!

Comment: read from where.? is it random number.? or asking user to enter.? please elaborate more.

Comment: yes you can. you are welcome

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do here. We won't be able to help you unless you provide more details.

Comment: If you are trying to get user input you can use Scanner for the task.

Comment: When user types H2, i want to read that 2 and than use is in calculations, but user can also type other numbers. For example H5 and than i need H * 5. Do i need to write every possible input s1.contains(H2) ; s1.contains(H3) or is some magic that can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by H * 5? What is H? Is it a number constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking, my guess is that s1 is a string of some sort and if the number exists you want to add it to a digit.

You can parse a String to a integer by useing the parseInt method in Integer class like this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(theNumberAsString);
```

Comment: And how can I parse exact digit in string? For example second digit?

Comment: You can get a part of a string by using the substring method see javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

If you want only digits from a string you can do like this str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");

Comment: That worked, one more question, how can i chech if that int is number? because I get int from that substring but it may also be normal character.

Comment: If it is a character it will be unparseable and thus throw a NumberFromatException, for more information see the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract number from a string like this

```
String str = "qwerty1qwerty2";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

now you will get the output as

```
[1, 2]
```

then use it for calculations

Answer (score 0):

This a simple example to get the data how `java.util.Scanner` works would be reading a single integer from   `System.in`.

It's really a simple.

Elaborate your question pls.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          n = in.nextInt();
          if ( n < 0 ){
              // write your code here
           }
```